Powershell script never stops running
I have a PS script that runs a script in a list of VMs within some subscription and gets a state of some agents and exports them on a CSV file.
The problem is that the script keeps iterating in loop after going through all the subscriptions an keeps running the script again on all the VMs.
Here is my script:
# List of your Azure subscription IDs
$subscriptionIds = @(
    "c0978b9d-b809-xxxxxx-xxxx-391ceb2cfdba",
    "c0978b9d-b809-xxxxxx-xxxx-391ceb2cfdba"
)
$scriptPath = "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Windows\CHECK_WINDOWS.ps1"
$outputFile = "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Windows\Outputfiles\StateWindows.csv"

# Set table header
$line1 = @"
"Server Name","GPO_HARMOR","BIOMEDIC_AGENT","EDWARD_STATUS","SENSOR_STATUS","SENTINEL_STATUS","VM_STATE"
"@
# Write table header
$line1 | Out-File -FilePath $outputFile

foreach ($subscriptionId in $subscriptionIds) {

    # Set the subscription context
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
 
    # Get resource groups with the specified tag
    $resourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup | Where-Object { $_.Tags -ne $null -and $_.Tags['ApplicationName'] -like "*US*" }

    foreach ($group in $resourceGroups) {

        # Disable RG lock
        $rgLock = Get-AzResourceLock -ResourceGroupName $group.ResourceGroupName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($rgLock) {
            Remove-AzResourceLock -LockId $rgLock.LockId -Force
            Write-Host "Removed existing lock on $($group.ResourceGroupName)"
        }

        # Get all the VMs in the subscription
        $vms = Get-AzVM
        # Loop through each VM and run the script if it's a Windows VM
        foreach ($vm in $vms) {
            # Disable VM lock
            $lock = Get-AzResourceLock -ResourceName $vm.Name -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -ResourceGroupName $group.ResourceGroupName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            if ($lock) {
                Remove-AzResourceLock -LockId $lock.LockId -Force
                Write-Host "Removed existing lock on $($vm.Name) in $($group.ResourceGroupName)"
            }

            $statuscheck = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name -Status

            # Check if the VM is ON and running a Windows OS
            if ($vm.StorageProfile.OSDisk.OSType -eq "Windows" -And $statuscheck.Statuses.DisplayStatus[1] -eq "VM running" -And $vm.Tags['ApplicationName'] -like "*OSS.NORAM.US*") {
                # Run the VARIASUIT_CHECK_WINDOWS.ps1 script on the VM
                Write-Host ">>>>>>> Getting state of $($vm.Name)"
                $scriptResult = Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -VMName $vm.Name -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath $scriptPath
                # Parse file to get state
                $state = @($scriptResult | Out-String -Stream) -match '^".*AZ-.*"$'
                $state >> $outputFile
                Write-Host "$($vm.Name) is RUNNING and it's $state"
            } elseif ($vm.StorageProfile.OSDisk.OSType -eq "Windows" -And $statuscheck.Statuses.DisplayStatus[1] -ne "VM running" -And $vm.Tags['ApplicationName'] -like "*OSS.NORAM.US*") {
                # "`""+$vm.Name+"`","+$state+"`""+"`""+$statuscheck.Statuses.DisplayStatus[1]+"`"">> $outputFile
                "`""+$vm.Name+"`","+"`"-`",`"-`",`"-`",`"-`",`"-`""+",`""+$statuscheck.Statuses.DisplayStatus[1]+"`"" >> $outputFile
                Write-Host "$($vm.Name) is STOPPED and it's $state"
            } elseif ($vm.Tags['ApplicationName'] -notlike "*OSS.NORAM.US*") {
                Write-Host "Skipping $($vm.Name) not a NORAM VM"
            } else {
                Write-Host "Skipping $($vm.Name) as it is not running a Windows OS"
            }

            # $scriptResult | Out-File $outputFileTemp

            # # Enable lock
            # New-AzResourceLock -LockLevel CanNotDelete -LockName "PreventDel" -LockNotes "PreventDel" -ResourceName $vm.Name -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -ResourceGroupName $group.ResourceGroupName -Force
            # Write-Host "Activated lock on $($vm.Name)   in $($group.ResourceGroupName)"

        }

    # Enable RG lock
    New-AzResourceLock -LockLevel CanNotDelete -LockName "PreventDel" -LockNotes "PreventDel" -ResourceGroupName $group.ResourceGroupName -Force
    Write-Host "Activated lock on $($group.ResourceGroupName)"

    # $results | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\tag.csv -NoTypeInformation
    }
    Write-Host "VM States of the subscription $subscriptionId are done"
}

Any help on how to break out of the loops once script go through all resources once? Thanks!

The issue you're facing is due to multiple loops without any clear termination or exit conditions

Your script continues to loop because there's nothing to break out of the loops once it has iterated over all the resources in the specified subscriptions. To prevent the script from running indefinitely, you can add a condition to break out of the loop after processing all the VMs.

You're making many API calls in your loop, it is expected this is gonna be slow however there is nothing in your code that would make it run indefinitely. If you wanted to speed this up you could try with ForEach-Object -Parallel.

@SantiagoSquarzon can you please detail more how I can run asynchrone calls? thanks

@VenkatV which condition I can add to break out?

@Arko which condition I can add to break out?

Do you have PowerShell 7+? ForEach-Object -Parallel is only available there. There is also the possibility to make this much more efficient by using Search-AzGraph and a KQL query

You can add the break condition in your code like here to stop the loop.

@woodyboow you can download and try this script from this link- https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/powershellscript/Check_VM_State.ps1 to break the loop and get your required details. Let me know if this helps

The issue with your script appears to be looping indefinitely because of an issue in the iteration logic
You can use the updated script below to iterate through each subscriptions and resource groups once, ensuring it doesn't loop indefinitely.
  
$subids = @(
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    )
    $scriptPath = "C:\Venkat\Powershellvm.ps1"
    $outputFile = "C:\Venkat\StateWindows.csv"
    
   
    $line1 = @"
    "Server Name","GPO_HARMOR","BIOMEDIC_AGENT","EDWARD_STATUS","SENSOR_STATUS","SENTINEL_STATUS","VM_STATE"
    "@

    $line1 | Out-File -FilePath $outputFile
    
    foreach ($subscriptionId in $subids) {
    
        # Set the subscription context
        Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
    
        # Get resource groups with the specified tag
        $rggroups = Get-AzResourceGroup
    
        foreach ($rggroup in $rggroups) {
    
            # Disable RG lock
            $rgLock = Get-AzResourceLock -ResourceGroupName $rggroup.ResourceGroupName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            if ($rgLock) {
                Remove-AzResourceLock -LockId $rgLock.LockId -Force
                Write-Host "Removed existing lock on $($rggroup.ResourceGroupName)"
            }
    
            # Get all the VMs in the resource group
            $vms = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rggroup.ResourceGroupName | Where-Object { $_.Tags -ne $null -and $_.Tags['ApplicationName'] -like "*US*" }
            # Loop through each VM and run the script if it's a Windows VM
            foreach ($vm in $vms) {
                # Disable VM lock
                $lock = Get-AzResourceLock -ResourceName $vm.Name -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -ResourceGroupName $rggroup.ResourceGroupName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                if ($lock) {
                    Remove-AzResourceLock -LockId $lock.LockId -Force
                    Write-Host "Removed existing lock on $($vm.Name) in $($rggroup.ResourceGroupName)"
                }
    
                $statuscheck = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name -Status
    
                # Check if the VM is ON and running a Windows OS
                if ($vm.StorageProfile.OSDisk.OSType -eq "Windows" -And $statuscheck.Statuses[1].DisplayStatus -eq "VM running" -And $vm.Tags['ApplicationName'] -like "*OSS.NORAM.US*") {
                    # Run the CHECK_WINDOWS.ps1 script on the VM
                    Write-Host ">>>>>>> Getting state of $($vm.Name)"
                    $scriptResult = Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -VMName $vm.Name -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath $scriptPath
                    # Parse file to get state
                    $state = @($scriptResult | Out-String -Stream) -match '^".*AZ-.*"$'
                    $state >> $outputFile
                    Write-Host "$($vm.Name) is RUNNING and its state is $state"
                } elseif ($vm.StorageProfile.OSDisk.OSType -eq "Windows" -And $statuscheck.Statuses[1].DisplayStatus -ne "VM running" -And $vm.Tags['ApplicationName'] -like "*OSS.NORAM.US*") {
                    "`""+$vm.Name+"`","+"`"-`",`"-`",`"-`",`"-`",`"-`""+",`""+$statuscheck.Statuses[1].DisplayStatus+"`"" >> $outputFile
                    Write-Host "$($vm.Name) is STOPPED and its state is $state"
                } elseif ($vm.Tags['ApplicationName'] -notlike "*OSS.NORAM.US*") {
                    Write-Host "Skipping $($vm.Name) as it is not a NORAM VM"
                } else {
                    Write-Host "Skipping $($vm.Name) as it is not running a Windows OS"
                }
            }
    
            # Enable RG lock
            New-AzResourceLock -LockLevel CanNotDelete -LockName "PreventDel" -LockNotes "PreventDel" -ResourceGroupName $rggroup.ResourceGroupName -Force
            Write-Host "Activated lock on $($rggroup.ResourceGroupName)"
        }
    
        Write-Host "VM States of the subscription $subscriptionId are done"
    }
    
    Write-Host "Script completed for all subscriptions"

Output:

